# Как в python указать относительный путь для файла?

Tags: python

Если в php я указываю `file_get_contents (__dir__ / path / file.txt)`

Подскажите как мне подобную запись сделать для питона?

Comment: Какую "подобную"?

Answer (score 1):

Если путь относителен файлу непосредственно переданного интерпретатору, то элементарно

```
open('path/file.txt')
```

Если какому-то из импортированных, то чуть сложнее

```
from os import path

parent_dir = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
with open(path.join(parent_dir, 'path', 'file.txt')) as fh:
    ...
```